# PHP CURL is not sending xml in post method

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am trying to connect with a telecom operator using their API Documentation.

I need to send XML request (in POST) to them along with some credentials in GET method.

I build my script and post XML, but they said they are not receiving any xml.

```
<?php
$url = "http://<IP>:<PORT>/C2SReceiver?LOGIN=abc&PASSWORD=123";
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <COMMAND>
            <TYPE>k59</TYPE>
            <DATE>19/03/2015 23:20:20</DATE>
            <PIN>11000009</PIN>
            <LOGINID>abc</LOGINID>
            <PASSWORD>123</PASSWORD>
            <EXTCODE>0100</EXTCODE>
            <EXTREFNUM>1230567890</EXTREFNUM>
        </COMMAND>';

    $headers = array(
        "Content-type: text/xml",
        "Content-length: " . strlen($xml),
        "Connection: close",
    );
    // configure
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    // requesting
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    // displaying response in XML
    echo $data;
    if(curl_errno($ch))
        print curl_error($ch);
    else
        curl_close($ch);
?>
```

When I send the request, their system says: "**Invalid Message format from HashMap**"

They said, they are only getting the parameters via get method. They didn't receive any XML.

**Please note:: if I change the xml format, their system response "Invalid XML".**

If they are not getting my XML, how could they say its invalid.

I've waste a full day to solve that. no idea whats going wrong. Please take a look and suggest me what can I do from my end.

Thanks.

Comment: do not add a content-length header manually, the chance of messing it up is big, and curl handles this automatically if you don't do it manually, and the chance of cURL messing it up is much smaller than the chance of you messing it up

Comment: don't add a "Connection: close" header either, should just set CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE=>true , it's why its there, i believe

Comment: I removed content-Length, still same error. any other possible fix?

Comment: I removed Connection: close, still same error.

Comment: Yes, do you have any implementation that actually works? monitor it, use a firewall or Fiddler Proxy (great if its SSL/TLS encrypted, fiddler has a great man-in-the-middle attack to monitor the decrypted version of this traffic, unnoticable to the application), or WPE Pro, then monitor your own curl implementation and compare the differences, something must be different, find out what

Comment: I am using Linux, and this is connected via VPN, is there any tool to test?

Comment: yes, reroute your program to a localhost netcat server (using iptables?), make both the working implementation and your curl implementation send the XML to 127.0.0.1:1337 , something like nc -l 1337 , then compare the 2, because, something in request must be different

Comment: Are you sure your request is correct? Can you issue a successful request using the `curl` (or `wget`) command line? The exposed PHP code looks fine and it produces the expected request (including the headers).

Comment: Sorry! I really don't have any idea of how to do that. I've changed the url to my another script and there I am receiving the xml. Is that enough to prove my request is ok? I just need to ensure that there is no fault from my end.

Comment: @axiac Yes, my request xml format is exactly same as they want.

Comment: no. the only guaranteed way to fix this, is to compare your curl request, with the working request, then fix/remove the differences, until your request is accepted

Comment: @hanshenrik they just gave me the request xml format, How to compare with working request? and one more thing, my same script is working fine  with another telecom operator. They both use same procedure except credentials. thats why I guess something wrong on their end.

Comment: uhh, do you have any program that sends a working xml request? (or a working reference request?) (if something is indeed wrong on their end, then maybe no working request exist :p )

Comment: @hanshenrik I just have a sample xml format (that never worked :( )

Comment: oh, i guess you're **effed then. I would tell the external party that i have reason to believe their system does not work, and ask them to verify that it does work.. at least..

Comment: As you know, BOSS is always right! I am telling them from yesterday, but the said their system is fine. I've connect to several APIs easily, but this make me feel idiot :(

Comment: Please make clear in your question which webservice you're referring to. Who is the vendor of that webservice? Where is the webservice specified? Where did you obtain the example code and why did you choose it? If you've written this your own, could you please explain why you did so and how the error messages come unexpected to you (that is just to write why do you think it should have worked). You need to provide more details and context to give better guidance here.

Comment: @hakre  Thanks for the advice. vendor didn't mentioned any web service, they just asked to post xml.

Comment: That's some service you send requests to over the web. Hence the term *webservice*. If vendor mentioned something, there at least is a vendor. What is the name of the vendor? Where did the vendor mentioned what you say? And how did you learn about to contact the vendor to ask questions?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the header content-type from text/xml -> application/xml. On my CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER when doing doing a HTTP request:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
```

Comment: Tried but same response.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code do not have any bug.I tested it to my end and i got the xml format data in **C2SReceiver.php** file.i just use this code for getting xml format data.

```
<?php $x = new SimpleXmlElement(file_get_contents('php://input')); print_r($x);die(); ?>
```

or

```
<?php $x = new SimpleXmlElement(file_get_contents('php://input')); print_r($x);die(); ?>
```

for getting xml data in C2SReceiver.php passed by curl

Comment: <?php
$x = new SimpleXmlElement(file_get_contents('php://input'));
print_r($x);die();
?>

Comment: <?php
$x = new SimpleXmlElement(file_get_contents('php://input'));
print_r($x);die();
?> for getting xml data in C2SReceiver.php passed by curl